# Let me filter out unanswered questions by excluding tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, filtering

When looking for questions I could possibly answer, I often use the 'favorite tags'. This gives a long list of unclosed questions related to the tag.

However many questions have a second or a third tag, indicating an environment I cannot support, e.g. `javascript` with a specific `.js` library.

It would be very usefull to select some of these tags in an `excluding tags` section, as to filter out unanswered questions with such tags, incresing the possibility I can help with the remaining questions.

Comment: Did you notice the *favourite tags* section on the right hand side of a question list? Click *edit* there and add ignored tags. Posts with those tags will be greyed out in the list, or, if you enable the feature in your preferences, *removed altogether* from question lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I apperently did not find this feature by intuition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature already exists. From the [help center on finding topics you are interested in](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics):

> ### Add favorite and ignored tags
>
> Another way to filter out questions you're not interested in and focus on the ones you do care about is to add favorite and ignored tags to your account.
>
> Favorite tags are meant to call out questions that are important or interesting to you. Any question tagged with one of your favorite tags will be highlighted on the homepage and questions lists.
>
> **Ignored tags downplay subjects you are not as interested in. Questions with these tags are faded on the homepage and questions list, but are still visible. If you want to completely hide questions with containing your ignored tags, you may checking the "Hide Ignored Tags" box in the "Preferences" tab of your profile's "Edit Profile & Settings" section on most sites, or on the "prefs" tab of your profile on certain other sites.**

Emphasis mine. See the help page for further details on how to manage these tags.